# Is it possible to integrate Firebase ML-Kit on Unity3D?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to install Firebase on Unity3D. Is it possible to integrate Firebase ML-Kit on Unity3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [list of Firebase products that are supported on Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#services_list), you will see that ML Kit is not included there at this time.

Keep an eye out on the [release notes for the Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity) to see when support is added.